# Am I paginating through a huge Firebase collection the right way?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I am trying to find a way to iterate all objects from a large collection of data in Firebase Database.

My best attempt follows but I found it odd for several reasons:

1. `startAt()` values are always inclusive. So after fetching 100 elements, I had to use my last fetched key as an argument to `startAt` which results in the last item being fetched again
2. `DataSnapshot`'s `forEach` method doesn't allow a callback with an index count as you would think it would based on JS's standards so I had to create a manual index - not sure it will work in every case as i'm not sure if `forEach` works perfectly synchronously

Here is my code, given the assumption my collection is located at `users`.

```
const mapAllTripsPaginated = function (database, childSnapshotCallback, start = '', limit = 100, totalNb = 0) {
  return database.ref('/users').orderByKey().startAt(start).limitToFirst(limit).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    let childrenPromises = []
    let lastChildKey = null
    let idx = 0
    snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
      lastChildKey = childSnapshot.key
      if (start !== '' && idx === 0) {
        // console.log(`Skipping ${childSnapshot.key} as 1st element of page`)
      } else {
        childrenPromises.push(childSnapshotCallback(childSnapshot))
      }
      idx = idx + 1
    })
    return Promise.all(childrenPromises)
    .then((result) => {
      let newTotal = totalNb + result.length
      if (snapshot.numChildren() === limit) {
        console.log(`Paginating from ${lastChildKey}`)
        return mapAllTripsPaginated(database, childSnapshotCallback, start = lastChildKey, limit = limit, totalNb = newTotal)
      } else {
        // Done paginating
        return newTotal
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Any idea on how I could make this method more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Firebase queries are inclusive both for their start and end conditions. You will indeed have to deduplicate the overlapping item on the client.
2. Firebase's `Snapshot.forEach()` is a synchronous operation.

I'd normally deduplicate based on already having the key of the item. That will also remove the need for the `idx` counter.

```
snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
  if (lastChildKey !== childSnapshot.key) {
    childrenPromises.push(childSnapshotCallback(childSnapshot))
  }
  lastChildKey = childSnapshot.key
})
```